# How to download and install IBM AS/400 database on window?

Tags: java, db2, db2-400

My requirement is to download and install db2/400 database on windows but I am unable to find the download option which can install db2/400 database on my window laptop. I can find drivers to connect with the db2/400 database but please help me get db2/400 database to be downloaded?

It will be very helpful if I can get a freeware/trial version/sand-box env or a free virtual image of db2/400?

Edited:

I found this link: [IBM Db2 for i](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1027715). It has an option to download for windows 64-bit machine.
Is that what I am looking for?

Comment: You  have not explained your motivation properly. Do you just want a database running on Microsoft-Windows that contains the same tables and data as an existing Db2-for-i-series database?

Comment: @mao I would like to install a fresh new dd2 database version AS400, add few Tables in db2 and try to connect to that database using JDBC driver in java code which can list all the Tables.

Comment: That is meaningless. It's easy to install a Db2-server product on Microsoft-Windows. That is the *Linux/Unix/Windows* version of Db2, which is different from "Db2 for i-series". .It's easy to recreate tables, and copy data from the "Db2 for i-series" database.  BUT *and this is what is important*  the Db2-server product itself is **NOT** identical between hardware platforms (x64, i-series, z/os), different functionality, different (but similar) SQL, different integration with the OS etc, different scheduling , different  administration . So once again, what is your *end goal* ? Think.

Comment: @mao Thank you for the clarification. I had dd2 database already installed on the windows machine and I am successfully connected with that using JDBC drivers. Similarly, I want to check if we can connect AS400 with using the same plain JDBC drivers or AS400 required some licensing files and special files in the classpath while making a connection. I have downloaded `IBM_DevelopmentPackage` for windows and it has sample code but I wonder it requires AS400 to check the sample code.  Does java code which connects AS400 required special files in the class path like liicense etc.?

Comment: There is a jdbc driver for i-series that does not require an IBM license file (which the official IBM drivers do require) . See http://jt400.sourceforge.net/ / .  The only way that you can use the *same* driver to connect to either LUW or i-series is to have an IBM-license, **OR** use a Db2-connect-gateway if already available at your site.

Comment: @mao Really appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question has already been answered , in that at present there are no working free emulators for IBM-i for x86 architectures. But the question did not explain the real end goal.

The motiviation behind the question appears to be a request for a driver to access the i-series via jdbc without needing to purchase additional IBM licenses.
That requirement may be met by the open source jt400 driver available at http://jt400.sourceforge.net/

Additional clarification is that while the jt400 jdbc driver lets you access i-series database, it is not for accessing Db2-LUW databases (e.g. on MS-Windows). To access Db2-LUW databases you need the (cost free) IBM jdbc drivers. Other jdbc drivers are also available from third parties, with different requirements for licensing.

For additional awareness, you need to know that the SQL used for accessing i-series database can be different from the SQL used to access either Db2-LUW databases or Db2-for-Z/OS databases. It's possible to use standard SQL that will work on all variants of Db2 but you will then be unable to harness the additional platform-specific power offered by each Db2-variant to properly exploit the platform.

If you want to use a single jdbc driver that can connect to any of Db2-LUW or Db2-for-iseries, or Db2-for-Z/OS then you can use an IBM-supplied driver. With that IBM driver for accessing either i-series or z/os then you must either supply a license file, (i.e. purchase the license) or use a pre-existing Db2-connect-gateway at your site (which is separately licensed and does not require per-workstation licensing). You don't need licenses just for connecting to Db2-LUW databases.

Answer (score 4):

No way.
There are no working `IBM i` emulators on x86 at the moment.

Comment: I found this link which downloads an i-series dd2 which was earlier called AS400 https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1027715. It has an option to download for windows 64-bit machine. Is that what I am looking for?

Comment: These are client tools & drivers and documentation. There is no x86 emulator of `IBM i` there.